# Customer Mobile Checkout DB desing

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am planing to build Customer Mobile Checkout Application for Retail Industry for mobile platform.

My problem is if the user buys same products many time what should I do whether i should increment the number or should make it as new entry.

If also any previous database design are available for such a system. Please give the link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common, here's an example:

You have invoices that contain information about the whole transaction.

```
invoices
    id              unsigned int(P)
    created         datetime
    customer_id     unsigned int(F customers.id)
    ...

+----+---------------------+-------------+-----+
| id | created             | customer_id | ... |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----+
|  1 | 2014-01-15 08:00:00 |           1 | ... |
| .. | ................... | ........... | ... |
+----+---------------------+-------------+-----+
```

And then you have a table that contains the specifics for each invoice. In my examle data you can see the customer purchased 13 Blue Widgets and 1 Red Widget.

```
invoice_items
    id              unsigned int(P)
    invoice_id      unsigned int(F invoices.id)
    item_id         unsigned int(F items.id)
    quantity        double
    ...

+----+------------+---------+----------+-----+
| id | invoice_id | item_id | quantity | ... |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-----+
|  1 |          1 |       1 |     13.0 | ... |
|  2 |          1 |       2 |      1.0 | ... |
| .. | .......... | ....... | ........ | ... |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-----+
```

And here are some example items. Obviously in a real-world scenario you would store more information than a description.

```
items
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(15)

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Blue Widget |
|  2 | Red Widget  |
| .. | ........... |
+----+-------------+
```